# Installed Phusion Passenger on Server but apache2 didn't install in /etc/apache2/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger

I am following instructions on how to deploy rails application on server.

I did the following:

```
sudo gem install passenger 
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Everything is successful so far. But next on instruction he uses:

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

Problem is there is no apache2 directory in etc. Therefore, I have no clue where the file I need to stick this information is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 

    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite/public 
    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/public> 
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 
            AllowOverride all 
            Order allow,deny 
            allow from all 
    </Directory> 

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log 

    LogLevel warn 

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined 

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is separate and will not be installed with phusion passenger. You need to install it by yourself and it depends on your OS (it seems you are on a linux system), so you may try something like this in the command line:

```
apt-get install apache2
```